# Problem with AddMenu Items in ASP.Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am generating menus and sub menus on the fly in my Master Page.

I have a link which points (AddMenu, and give url to the logoff page) to a generic logoff page. It is a html page. Before logging off, I make sure that the Sessions are aborted and cleared.

When I deploy this application on Servers, the application fails to come up.

To correct, I add a new aspx page. say Logout.aspx
When I click on Logout link on the master page -- I add menu item -- to point ot Logout.aspx.

In the Page_Load event of Logout.aspx, I clear the sessions and then Response.Redirect to the logoff page (which I was doing in the Master Page initially).

This case the sessions are working perfectly fine. What could be the possible reason for it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is going on.  So far, when you deploy to the servers, it doesn't run?  As far as the problem you've described, I would look at the Page_Load event of the Logout.aspx page.  Are there any logs or error messages you could post?

Comment: How can you clear sessions from a html page? doesn't it have to be an aspx page because there is some server side code involved ?

Comment: 1) I was adding the menu item -- AddMenu to the master page and it was redirecting to the logoff.html page. 2) Had writeen an event on click of the added menu item to clear the sessions. ie. clear the sessions and go to the logoff page. 3)It did not work. 4)So I added a Logout.aspx page. 5)Pointed the logout link on Master page to this page in application. 6)Cleared sessions in Page_Load method and then redirected to the logoff.html. 7)It worked good. 8)My question was why?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My issue was solved but I posted this to be sure why this issue surfaced in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand it sounds like you initially were trying to clear the session in the master page code-behind. This code was supposedly tied to the logoff menu item but you said the item was a 'link which points to a generic logoff page'.

My guess is you were expecting the link to trigger a postback to the masterpage when it was actually just directing the user to the html page.

When you moved the code to the Page_Load of the new Logoff.aspx page, your session clearing code was triggered correctly when they requested the Logoff.aspx page.

If this is the case, what you have found is that there is a big difference between the following

```
<a href="Logoff.html">Logoff</a>
```

and

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="linkLogoff" runat="server" Text="Logoff" />
```

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. Checked the view source for the page, and found that the menu item added was ..<a class="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1 ctl00_NavigationMenu_3 leftPanelHeaderStyle ctl00_NavigationMenu_5" href="Logout.aspx" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">